# How to add a horizontal mean line and annotation to each facet

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, facet-grid

I have a simple FacetGrid of 2 row and 1 column with lineplots denoting different categories for the facets - image below.

```
# lineplot for each Category over the last three years
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="Category", sharey=False, sharex=False, height=2.5, aspect = 3)
g = g.map(plt.plot, 'Date', 'Count')
```

[image]

How do I add a reference line and annotation showing the mean Count for each facet?

### Sample Data

- Read the sample dataframe with

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Category': ['Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1',
                     'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2',
                     'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2', 'Group 2'],
        'Date': ['2017-01-31', '2017-02-28', '2017-03-31', '2017-04-30', '2017-05-31', '2017-06-30', '2017-07-31', '2017-08-31', '2017-09-30', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-30', '2017-12-31', '2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30', '2018-05-31', '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-31', '2018-09-30', '2018-10-31', '2018-11-30', '2018-12-31',
                 '2019-01-31', '2019-02-28', '2019-03-31', '2019-04-30', '2019-05-31', '2019-06-30', '2019-07-31', '2019-08-31', '2019-09-30', '2017-01-31', '2017-02-28', '2017-03-31', '2017-04-30', '2017-05-31', '2017-06-30', '2017-07-31', '2017-08-31', '2017-09-30', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-30', '2017-12-31', '2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31',
                 '2018-04-30', '2018-05-31', '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-31', '2018-09-30', '2018-10-31', '2018-11-30', '2018-12-31', '2019-01-31', '2019-02-28', '2019-03-31', '2019-04-30', '2019-05-31', '2019-06-30', '2019-07-31', '2019-08-31', '2019-09-30'],
        'Count': [226, 235, 236, 221, 187, 218, 225, 221, 248, 224, 204, 224, 218, 241, 196, 246, 256, 217, 229, 230, 222, 215, 226, 227, 232, 233, 224, 214, 243, 214, 235, 218, 208, 208, 254, 223, 227, 245, 222, 226, 235, 225, 226, 258, 234, 257, 224, 228, 222, 227, 256, 217, 243, 230, 250, 197, 232, 248, 232, 259, 259, 229, 228, 234, 218, 231]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

#### `df.head()`

```
  Category       Date  Count
0  Group 1 2017-01-31    226
1  Group 1 2017-02-28    235
2  Group 1 2017-03-31    236
3  Group 1 2017-04-30    221
4  Group 1 2017-05-31    187
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As per the **Warning** in [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html), it is better to use [figure-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) functions like [`sns.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html).

```py
g = sns.relplot(data=df, kind='line', x='Date', y='Count', row='Category', height=2.5, aspect=3, facet_kws={'sharey': True, 'sharex': False})
g.fig.tight_layout()

# draw lines:
for m, ax in zip(df.groupby('Category').Count.mean(), g.axes.ravel()):
    ax.hlines(m, *ax.get_xlim())
    ax.annotate(f'Mean: {m:0.0f}', xy=(ax.get_xlim()[1], m))
```

[image]

- This also works for other figure-level plots like [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html).

```py
g = sns.catplot(data=df, kind='bar', x='Date', y='Count', row='Category', height=2.5, aspect=3)
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)

# draw lines:
for m, ax in zip(df.groupby('Category').Count.mean(), g.axes.ravel()):
    ax.hlines(m, *ax.get_xlim())
    ax.annotate(f'Mean: {m:0.0f}', xy=(ax.get_xlim()[1], m))
```

[image]

---

You can manually draw the horizontal line on each of the axes:

`zip(list1, list2)` is similar to `[(list1[0], list2[0]), (list1[1], list2[1]),...]`. In this code it means m is the mean, ax is the axis in the facets. `ravel()` turns n-dimension `np.array` into 1D array so you can `zip`. `ax.hlines(y_val, x_min, x_max)` draw a horizontal line at `y_val` from `x_min` to `x_max`. Here the two x values are provided by `*ax.get_xlim()`.

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="Category", sharey=False, sharex=False, height=2.5, aspect = 3)
g = g.map(plt.plot, 'Date', 'Count')

# draw lines:
for m,ax in zip(df.groupby('Category').Count.mean(), g.axes.ravel()):
    ax.hlines(m,*ax.get_xlim())
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

- As per the **Warning** in [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html), it is better to use [figure-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) functions like [`sns.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html).

```py
g = sns.relplot(data=df, kind='line', x='Date', y='Count', row='Category', height=2.5, aspect=3, facet_kws={'sharey': True, 'sharex': False})
g.fig.tight_layout()


def custom(y, **kwargs):
    ym = y.mean()
    plt.axhline(ym, color="orange", linestyle="dashed")
    plt.annotate(f"mean: {y.mean():.3f}", xy=(1,ym), 
                 xycoords=plt.gca().get_yaxis_transform(), ha="right")
    

g = g.map(custom, 'Count')
```

[image]

---

Just a single line is enough

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="Category", sharey=False, sharex=False, height=2.5, aspect = 3)
g = g.map(plt.plot, 'Date', 'Count')

# add this to get a horizontal line
g = g.map(lambda y, **kw: plt.axhline(y.mean(), color="k"), 'Count')
```

[image]

To make the line orange and dashed and add an annotation, you could do

```py
def custom(y, **kwargs):
    ym = y.mean()
    plt.axhline(ym, color="orange", linestyle="dashed")
    plt.annotate(f"mean: {y.mean():.3f}", xy=(1,ym), 
                 xycoords=plt.gca().get_yaxis_transform(), ha="right")
    

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="Category", sharey=False, sharex=False, height=2.5, aspect = 3)
g = g.map(plt.plot, 'Date', 'Count')
    
g = g.map(custom, 'Count')
```

[image]